# Change data type from Factors to Date in R

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, factors

I'm pulling out data from a sql, one of the fields are date type but from some reason R recognize this data as Factors.

this is how R recognize this field:

```
 $ RegDate    : Factor w/ 666 levels "2015-02-02","2015-02-03",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
```

I tried several ways to change the type like

`as.Date(RawDate$RegDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` - didn't change anything

`as.POSIXct(x,format="%Y-%m-%d)` - when I used this kind of funcation i got all NAs

Any idea how should I do this?
Thanks

Comment: You have to convert it to `Date` class with `as.Date(RawDate$RegDate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a `format` issue.  The 'RegDate' is already in the same format as `Date` class.  So, what we need is just wrapping with `as.Date`

```
RawDate$RegDate <- as.Date(RawDate$RegDate)
```

---

The reason why it got read as a `factor` variable is because of the default option `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` for `character` elements in `read.csv/read.table` or from whatever function you used.   One way, is to specify the `colClasses` argument in `read.csv/read.table`